# How can I stop nested setTimeout with clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `everyXsecsForYsecs` that will accept three arguments: a function, an interval time in seconds, and a total time in seconds.

`everyXsecsForYsecs` should invoke the given function every `X * 1000` milliseconds, yet then stop invoking the function after `Y * 1000` milliseconds. Addition to this, here is a simple callback function for `everyXsecsForYsecs`:

```
function sayHowdy(){
  console.log('Howdy');
}
```

Then I call `everyXsecsForYsecs` as such:

```
everyXsecsForYsecs(sayHowdy, 1, 5);
```

So what I expect is to see 5 'Howdy' in the console, then function to stop. But what happens is that, function prints 'Howdy' for ever. Here is how I implemented `everyXsecsForYsecs`,

```
function everyXsecsForYsecs(callback, X, Y) {
  x_mili = X * 1000;
  y_mili = Y * 1000;

let id = setTimeout(function run(){
    callback();
    id = setTimeout(run, x_mili);
  }, x_mili);
setTimeout(clearTimeout, y_mili, id);
}
```

I am suspicious about how I use `clearTimeout` with nested `setTimeout`,
What I am missing exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time

```
 setTimeout(clearTimeout, y_mili, id);
```

runs, `id` contains the timer id of *the first outer `setTimeout` call*. Cancelling that won't really help. If you'd replace it with:

```
 setTimeout(() => clearTimeout(id),  y_mili);
```

it'll clear the timeout with the `id` *at that time*, as you evaluate `id` *when the timeout is done*, and not *when it get's started*.

---

I'd write it as:

```
 function everyXsecsForYsecs(callback, X, Y) {
   let count = Math.floor(Y / X);
   function recurring() {
      callback();
      if((count -= 1) >= 0)
        setTimeout(recurring, X * 1000);
  }
  setTimeout(recurring, X * 1000);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, every basic mistake by me.

Answer (score 1):

```
let firstId = setTimeout(sayHowdy, 1000)
```

> will call sayHowdy after 1000ms and store the timeout id within firstId

```
clearTimeout(firstId)
```

> if this is called, the timeout referenced by the id will be cleared (no matter if it already is over or not)

But the question actually is, why you would want to clear the timeout, it's no interval, so you probably are in the wrong box.

have a look at this snippet, it does not repeat for seconds, but x times with recursion:

```
function fireAllXSecsYTimes(callback, fireAfterSeconds, counter) {
  if (counter === 0) {
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    counter--;
    fireAllXSecsYTimes(callback, fireAfterSeconds, counter);
  }, fireAfterSeconds * 1000)
}
```

what you asked for:

```
function fireAllXSecsForYSecs(callback, fireAfterSeconds, remainingSeconds) {
  if (remainingSeconds <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    fireAllXSecsForYSecs(callback, fireAfterSeconds, remainingSeconds - fireAfterSeconds);
  }, fireAfterSeconds * 1000)
}
```

called with `fireAllXSecsForYSecs(() => console.log('howdy'), 2, 5)`
it will log 'howdy' 3 times, because on third execution, `remainingSeconds` still has 1 left. If you want to prevent this, just return if `remainingSeconds <= 0 || remainingSeconds < fireAfterSeconds`

Comment: Actually, only reason the way I did is to be able to use nested timeout and stop it. And of course, snippet you provided is also a reasonable solution. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, as I understand you code, you just cleared the timeout after y_mili, but actually your timeout with x_mili has already run at this time, so no need to clear it. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the reference not the value.

```js
function sayHowdy() {
  console.log('Howdy');
}

function everyXsecsForYsecs(callback, X, Y) {
  x_mili = X * 1000;
  y_mili = Y * 1000;
  let id = setTimeout(function run() {
    callback();
    id = setTimeout(run, x_mili);
  }, x_mili);
  setTimeout(() => clearTimeout(id), y_mili);
  //here you need to pass the reference to the id not the value
    //which is constantly changing
}
everyXsecsForYsecs(sayHowdy, 1, 5);
```